# Activator.getDefault().getLog() nullpointer exception

Tags: eclipse, logging, osgi

In my Plugin, I have a Util class which using eclipse default log, like below

```
private static ILog log = Activator.getDefault().getLog();
```

It works during plugin in runtime. But when i try to test this Util class at java application ,it got **Nullpointer Exception** at `Activator.getfault().getLog()` , how to solve this problem?

Comment: looks like using Plugin Junit Test could solve this problem.

Comment: You can't use plugin code in a plain Java application as there is a lot of setup that has to be done by the Eclipse plugin system.